# How to resolve Invalid Audience when I trye to verify if a user exists in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, microsoft-graph-api, token

Reading the documentation of Microsoft Graph, I found an example to connect to the Azure Active Directory and verify if a previously registered user exists.

The problem is that the example throws this error when I try to do the request:

```
Graph service exception Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.
```

My code is practically the same as the documentation shows how to do it. This is the code:

```
List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();


String clientId = "XXXXXXX";
String clientSecret = "YYYYYYYY";
String tenantId = "ZZZZZZZZZ";

String permissions = "api://" + clientId + "/.default";


scopes.add(permissions);

final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(clientSecret)
        .tenantId(tenantId)
        .build();


final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider =
        new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);


final GraphServiceClient graphClient =
        GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                .buildClient();

User resultUser =  null;

try {
    UserCollectionPage ucp = graphClient.users().buildRequest().filter(
            "startsWith(mail,'" + email + "')").get();


    List<User> result = ucp.getCurrentPage();
    User u = result.get(0);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(resultUser, HttpStatus.OK);
}
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
```

The connection to the Azure Active Directory looks fine, because it shows SUCCESS after login connection with the credentials:

```
2021-12-16 21:38:10.994  INFO 28072 --- [onPool-worker-1] 
c.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential  : 
Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes api://570f77fe-098f-42cd-8a22-a29fa1d9c7c0/.default: SUCCESS
```

Another thing I want to show you, is the decoded token, may it can helps to bring me a solution:

Token:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1yNS1BVWliZkJpaTdOZDFqQmViYXhib1hXMCIsImtpZCI6Ik1yNS1BVWliZkJpaTdOZDFqQmViYXhib1hXMCJ9.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.SU9kpXWs6fP-9T8QlPOJT8rKihPdtd38B8frOiS1I36T5LjewEyTmHgTEKWKgPhGxUHkmYWQxi6itNsn_4H_XUpgvVU2oNxoYsumQIW8rQZUx7hZeqxPrY3hbl_UfJgCtZ3J_0z6Ekk6QmBA-VBFEueq5lzjlARqYgTyQQ-uaNUtyrih4HyOkSkwcC8rs20UAjguunDVAzVucjweB0B2m9ib-uT1hhJlOihOwNtZ-A28QYNihp4r8HkriMaZMqutrdrVhH_--0OpF1O7lFEGEeDQeDozWi4SjboWJcODgsOGsZ7HxHd3Lx5mv8vJ0MvC8z_GIRWpuQqJuZ7eXQeFWg
```

Decoded token:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "Mr5-AUibfBii7Nd1jBebaxboXW0",
  "kid": "Mr5-AUibfBii7Nd1jBebaxboXW0"
}.{
  "aud": "api://570f77fe-098f-42cd-8a22-a29fa1d9c7c0",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/397ed031-3935-40b0-9c69-14fd1164db8f/",
  "iat": 1639708399,
  "nbf": 1639708399,
  "exp": 1639712299,
  "aio": "E2ZgYNi2cDa/xtG2feu01Q7qTr51AgA=",
  "appid": "570f77fe-098f-42cd-8a22-a29fa1d9c7c0",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/397ed031-3935-40b0-9c69-14fd1164db8f/",
  "oid": "b2dea475-e89a-4b64-8c92-21880c988f16",
  "rh": "0.ASkAMdB-OTU5sECcaRT9EWTbj_53D1ePCc1CiiKin6HZx8ApAAA.",
  "sub": "b2dea475-e89a-4b64-8c92-21880c988f16",
  "tid": "397ed031-3935-40b0-9c69-14fd1164db8f",
  "uti": "3QCXIdhLMUKRxw6LpnwhAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]
```

I get this token with this URL:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/

Using the following code:

```
 url = new URL(urlHost);
            token = tokenCredentialAuthProvider.getAuthorizationTokenAsync(url).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Work around on the error **InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: Access token validation failure. Invalid audience**

**aud (audience) :** this Identifies the intended recipient of the token - its audience.

Your API must validate this value and reject the token if the value doesn't match.

Based on your given details   you are using version v1.0

**In v1.0 tokens it can be the client ID or the resource URI used in the request, depending on how the client requested the token**

To resolve this error, you need to make sure the **audience** in the token is **https://graph.microsoft.com** by using scope: **https://graph.microsoft.com/.default** during your token acquisition call

make sure below permissions are consented under the application whose client ID you are using during token acquisition call.

```
1)User.ReadWrite.All
2)Directory.ReadWrite.All
```

To provide consent, you need to navigate to:

**1) Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App Registration > search the application using client ID > API Permissions > Add Permission**

[image]

**2) Click on the ADD Permission**

[image]

Comment: I think it is something with the JBOSS and the Eclipse, Because I Deployed the WAR uploading it manually to the JBOSS Web Console and it is deployed fine! I don't what is wrong with eclipse!